# Speeding up for loops in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, linear-regression

I need a hand at solving this problem. I have a for loop that iterates on a list and builds a linear model for each item on that list. I have built a python for loop, but my list of items can get very lengthy and I know I am probably not taking advantage of all Spark has to offer. So here is my code:

```
for i in items:
    
        df_item = df.where(col("items")==i)

        vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['x'], outputCol = 'features')
        vector_df = vectorAssembler.transform(dt)
        premodel_df = vector_df.select(['features', 'Y'])
        lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='y_pred', maxIter=10, regParam=0, elasticNetParam=0)
        lr_model = lr.fit(premodel_df)
        r_squared = lr_model.summary.r2
        item = i
        lr_info = (Row(item=i
                     ,r2=r_squared)
                     )

        lm_results = lm_results.union(lm_info)
```

I therefore need some sort of examples that will help in speeding up the process

Comment: You can always use a map function instead of for loops. Check out the map function here https://realpython.com/python-map-function/

Comment: You can use map transformation on dataframes too check out the below link https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-transformation/

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question using the function applyInPandas. I had to switch to the python statsmodels library to perform the regression:

```
import pandas as pd  
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import statsmodels.api as sm
schema =  StructType([ \
                    StructField("item",StringType(),True), \                       
                    StructField("intercept",DoubleType(),True), \
                    StructField("slope",DoubleType(),True), \
                    StructField("rsquared",DoubleType(),True) \ \
                                 ])

def ols(pdf):
                group_key = pdf['item'].iloc[0]
                y = pdf[y_column]
                X = pdf[x_column]
                X = sm.add_constant(X)
                model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

                return pd.DataFrame([[group_key] 
                                     + [model.params[0]]
                                     + [model.params[1]]
                                     + [model.rsquared]
                                    ]

                                    , columns=[group_column] + ['intercept']+ ['slope'] + ['rsquared'] )
result = df.groupby(group_column).applyInPandas(ols,schema)
```

I hope this can help someone!

Comment: What is the improvement in running time?

Comment: I used to wait for 12 minutes with the loop and now it runs in less than 5 seconds